# starting threads and invoking join using lambdas

Tags: java, multithreading, lambda

```
private List<Thread> pupils = new ArrayList<>();

public (int groupNo, Position pos)
{
    this.groupNo = groupNo;
    this.position = pos;

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        pupils.add(new Thread(new Pupil(i, groupNo, pos)));
    }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    pupils.forEach(t -> t.start());
    // Here I would like to use Java 8 features instead of Iterator to loop through list
    // of threads and start a thread at once. Only when one is complete start the next
    // in order.
}
```

I have a List of `Threads` which I would like to start in turn. Once one is finished with its task, next one takes over the baton if you like and does its tasks. How can I iterate the list in order and start the threads with Java lambda body handling the `InterruptedException` as a result of `join()` call?

Comment: the second line seems to be a function declaration but it doesn't have a name

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to wait for each thread to finish before starting the next.  You might just as well do all of the work in one thread.

Don't use `Thread` objects (or `Foobar extends Thread` objects) to represent things in your data model.  That violates the *single responsibility principle*.  Use threads to do work, or use threads to wait for asynchronous events.  Use other objects in your model.